# Julia variable disappears/changes

Tags: julia

I have the following MWE

```
function f(p)
  ans = zeros(p, 2)
  return ans
end

ans = f(2)

ans

b=ans.+1.0
ans
```

At first, `ans` is correct, but the operation creating `b` overwrites `ans`.

```
julia> ans = f(2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> ans
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> b=ans.+1.0
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> ans
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

It's a fresh install of julia 1.6.5.

The same thing happens if I just ask `typeof(ans)`. The value of `ans` itself changes to the output of `typeof(ans)` which is a DataType.

```
julia> ans=f(2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> typeof(ans)
Matrix{Float64} (alias for Array{Float64, 2})

julia> typeof(ans)
DataType
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docstring of `ans`:

```
help?> ans
  ans

  A variable referring to the last computed value, automatically set at the interactive prompt.
```

So as you can see Julia REPL automatically overwrites `ans` after each evaluation of an expression.

In short it is recommended not to use `ans` in a global scope in interactive sessions (except to get the result of last operation).

Comment: Well that's embarrassing on my part. Thank you!